# Invalid or missing URL scheme hackbook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am trying to use facebook ios sdk but when I run the Hackbook example it gives me the error message "Invalid or missing URL scheme. You cannot run the app unti you set up a valid URL scheme in your .plist" Where do I make the changes for this?

Since one of the answers mentioned it, I will say that I have already modified the plist to have fb[my_app_id] in the URLSchemes.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso) walks you through the process step by step, search for "Modify the app property list file".

Comment: Sadly I have already modified the URL Scheme in the plist file to be fb[my_app_id]. Any other possibilities it could be?

Comment: Put this in you code (e.g. in the launching method in the AppDelegate):
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"]);

Does it show this:

(
        {
        CFBundleURLSchemes =         (
            fb[your app id]
        );
    }
)

?

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to update a section they never mentioned.

Comment: Which section is that? I never ran into that problem but I would like to be aware of it in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was another instance in the code where the ID needed to be replaced. What's odd is that it's not specifically called out as far as I can tell. I did a search for it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add like this
100% works and solved crash
[image]